# Specify entry point for electron in env file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, package.json

I am working on creating a desktop application for my react website using electron

Electron requires the entry point to be specified in `package.json` file. But setting `main: "electron/app.js"` as entry point affects my website

1. Is it possible to set the entry point in env file?
2. Is there any option to provide electron entry point separately?

I would like to use electron without affecting my website